# What are the safe values for CONFIG_FRAME_WARN on x86 arch?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, gcc-warning

I am compiling driver modules and getting warnings like `warning: the frame size of 1064 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes`
Yep, it means the space allocated in stack for local variables is big a slightly.

But what is the maximum safe value?

I cannot rely on http://elinux.org/Kernel_Small_Stacks that says up to 8192 bytes.
There are no significant sources.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux kernel defines stack size 8192 bytes for each kernel thread, so the maximum safe value is the value that will not overflow total of 8192 bytes in the whole call path.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific safe value.

What matters is how much stack is actually used, i.e., the sum of the stack frames of all active functions.

This warning does not *guarantee* that you will overflow the stack space; it just shows that this function makes an overflow more likely (when used together with other big-frame functions, or with many smaller functions).